# How I create an enum from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, enums

I need to generate an `enumErrorList` like this

```
Errors={
    none:0,
    subject:1,
    content:2,
    sender:4,
    recipient:8
}
```

from an array like this

```
let errors=[
        'none',
        'subject',
        'content',
        'sender',
        'recipient'
]
```

but I’m sorry I’m not very familiar with enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the array then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to generate an object there where:

- The key is the item from the array.
- The value grows by a power of 2 starting from zero.

```js
let errors=[
        'none',
        'subject',
        'content',
        'sender',
        'recipient'
]

const Errors = errors.reduce(
  (acc, item, index) => Object
    .assign(
      acc, 
      {[item]: Math.floor(2 ** (index - 1))}
    ), 
  {}
)

console.log(Errors)
```

Or via bit arithmetic to only produce powers of 2 by setting bit `n-1` starting with `0` when `n=0`:

```js
let errors=[
        'none',
        'subject',
        'content',
        'sender',
        'recipient'
]

const Errors = errors.reduce(
  (acc, item, index) => Object
    .assign(
      acc, 
      {[item]: (1 << index) >> 1}
    ), 
  {}
)

console.log(Errors)
```

Comment: thanks you have been very kind and exhaustive in your reply

Answer (score 2):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) as follows

```js
let errors=[
        'none',
        'subject',
        'content',
        'sender',
        'recipient'
]

let Errors = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(errors).map(([a,b]) => [b, ((1<<a)>>1)]));
console.log(Errors)
```

Comment: Right, well done with the `|0`. I was wracking my brain trying to figure out how to make it with bitwise operations only since `1 << index` was the correct way...aside from `0`. For some reason I completely forgot I ignored I could just use two operations. Your `/2` reminded me of that, so it finally clicked `1 << index >> 1` to only set bit `n-1` which happens to be no bits for `index = 0`.

Comment: d'oh ... of course << then >> :p - I had a seniors moment :p

Comment: Don't worry, I did as well. I know the feeling :D